# qt6 Positioning/Location on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt6

I implemented a class that gives me the GPS-Location for my app. Here a minimal example:

```cpp
rbManager::rbManager(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    nm = nullptr;
    initialized = false;

    QLocationPermission locationPermission;
    locationPermission.setAccuracy(QLocationPermission::Precise);

    if(qApp->checkPermission(locationPermission) != Qt::PermissionStatus::Granted) {
        qApp->requestPermission(QLocationPermission{}, this, &rbManager::permissionUpdated);
    } else {
        qDebug() << "PERMISSION ALREADY GRANTED";
        init();
    }
}

void rbManager::permissionUpdated(const QPermission &permission) {
    if (permission.status() == Qt::PermissionStatus::Granted) {
        qDebug() << "PERMISSION GRANTED";
        init();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "PERMISSION NOT GRANTED";
    }
}
```

The init function does something with the gps coordinates. On iOS everything works like expected. However on Android it does not work!

I did everything which was mentioned in the qt6 docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlocationpermission.html

I used `QLocationPermission::Precise` as you can see in my C++ code. And I put this

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in my manifest.

On the console I get this output:

```
D libCloudLogOffline_arm64-v8a.so: INIT
I qt.positioning.android: Unknown positioningMethod
I qt.positioning.android: Unknown positioningMethod
W qt.positioning.android: : Position data not available due to missing permission
```

So what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: Also I should mention, that when the app is installed and started for the first time, I'm asked only for approximate location... Maybe there is a bug in Qt?